# Get rid of vscode visual scrollbar

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I get rid of this thing in the Editor? I never use it, yet it occupies valuable space on the screen:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VSCode, it is called the MiniMap, you can disable it by going to `View->Show MiniMap` and toggle it.

[image: mimimap toggle]

The `settings.json` way is to disable it by setting

```js
"editor.minimap.enabled": false
```

Comment: @Mark Then please mark duplicate. I was just answering his question.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91180/is-it-my-responsibility-to-search-for-duplicates-vote-to-close-before-answerin/105231#105231

Comment: @Mark noted. Ty